# NSMutableArray sort cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have in tableView NSMutableArray "days" which contain 6 NSMutableArray (monday, tuesday...saturday)

Before I doing sort,this method is work

```
tuesday = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tuesday sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id cont1, id cont2) { return [[(Lesson *) cont1 time1] compare:[(Lesson *) cont2 time1]]; }]];
```

but now I must doing [days objectAtIndex:0]=.... but how I do this if this expression is unacceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign an object to a `NSMutableArray` with the equal sign, use the following:

```
[days addObject:theObjectYouWantToAdd];
```

**EDIT:**

In case you would like to add the new object to a particular position on the original mutable array (say position 0), you have to remove the old one by:

```
[days removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Ant then insert the new one by:

```
[days insertObject:theObjectYouWantToInsert atIndex:0];
```